# Java swing: setBounds method not working if I don't call a setLayout method?

Tags: java, swing, oop

I'm new in programming but I'm a bit knowledgeable in OOP and I'd like to learn more.

While learning Java swing, I realized that the setBounds method isn't working without calling the setLayout method. Why is that?

```
import javax.swing.*;  
public class FirstSwingExample {  

public static void main(String[] args) {  
    JFrame f=new JFrame();//creating instance of JFrame  
          
    JButton b=new JButton("click");//creating instance of JButton  
    b.setBounds(130,100,100, 40);//x axis, y axis, width, height  
          
    f.add(b);//adding button in JFrame  
          
    f.setSize(400,500);//400 width and 500 height  
   // f.setLayout(null);//using no layout managers-> setBounds won't work without calling setLayout
    f.setVisible(true);//making the frame visible  
}  
}
```

Now another question, if I used the same concept in another program like the Animal inheritance as a superclass.

If I have a Cat class with the run method... How can I create the run method that is dependent on the eat method from an Animal class?

What I mean is, how can you call a run method in Cat class that will work only if you also call the eat method?

```
 Animal class -> superclass (method: eat())
     |    
     Feline class -> subclass of Animal
         |
         Cat class -> subclass of Feline (method: run())
```

Comment: You asking two different questions here which are not related to each other. You can search on web to understand inheritance mechanism. You will find loads of good articles.

Comment: I understand inheritance.  My question is same concept but a different examples. How can you create a method in a subclass that is dependent on another method?  Like you can only call the method properly when you also call the other method from another class?

Comment: As far as I understand your question, you need to call `eat()` method in super class when you call `run()` method in child class?

Comment: No, I need to call the run() method, which is dependent on eat() method. Example: The run() method won't work properly without also calling the eat() method, the same concept in the example code I provided. Like If I don't eat, I can't  run..

Comment: What you are looking for, can be achieved using aspect oriented programming (Like how Spring framework supports). The scenario "I need to EAT first to RUN" is not related to inheritance.

Comment: In Swing, `setBounds()` on the button doesn't work without calling `setLayout(null)` on the frame because frames use `LayoutManager`s to manage the bounds of the added components (the `LayoutManager` calls `setBounds()` on the button for you)

Comment: *I'm new in programming ... and I'd like to learn more* - Don't use setBounds() and don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers for many reasons. Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples.